# Netbeans - Turn off - wavy red underlines - How?

Tags: netbeans, settings

How can I turn off the wavy red underlines in Netbeans? I don't want to be interrupted while I'm typing, and told that a half finished line of code is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This has actually already been addressed and illustrated in Arnold's answer to [NetBeans. Disable error checking underline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3693583/45773) (+1); select *Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Syntax -> Category Error* and adjust the font effects (or any other style) to your liking:

[image]

I've confirmed it to still work like so - please note that new settings won't have any effect until you trigger an editor update, e.g. by typing a letter.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to help with performance in any immediately observable way (though removing font effects like this indeed used to speed up things in the olden days).

Comment: This doesn't disable it quite like the question is asking, I think. The question asks to delay the error checking until the line is completed, but your answer removes it completely.

Comment: Yes, @gobernador is absolutely right, this doesn't disable spell checking, it just "hides" the error underlinings; the OP seemed to be disturbed by spell checking. (I don't really understand why this answer got a +50 bounty, because this is not a solution at all. Sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

Follow this path if you want to turn them off, (I'm using NeatBeans 5.5.1)

Tools ->
Options ->
Advanced Options ->
Open the "Editing" node and click on "Java sources" ->
Enter 0 for the "Error Annotation Limit"

That will completely turn off the red underlines. You can also change the "automatic parsing delay" at the same location if you want a longer pause instead.