# Netbeans 6.1 (!5.5.1) - Turn off - wavy red underlines - How?

Tags: netbeans6.1

How can I turn off the wavy red underlines in Netbeans? I don't want to be interrupted while I'm typing, and told that a half finished line of code is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here [Netbeans - Turn off - wavy red underlines - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236733/netbeans-turn-off-wavy-red-underlines-how) seems to be more accurate… (though the Mac version of Netbeans 5.6.1 doesn't seem to have an ‘Advanced’ menu)

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors

Select "All Languages" in the Language list. Select "Error" in the Category list. On the right, select "None" in the Effects list and hit Ok.