# NetBeans. Disable error checking underline

Tags: netbeans

How to disable error checking in NetBeans 6.9.1?
It is very annoying to have red line in the source code.

This is similar to [NetBeans - Turn off - wavy red underlines - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236733/netbeans-turn-off-wavy-red-underlines-how), but I want to disable underlines at all, not only when typing.

(It incorrectly parses PHP sources and omits syntax errors.)

Answer (score 4):

Netbeans has a vast array of settings but this might do it. Try changing the drop down labelled "Wave Underlined" to "None":

[image]

**Update:**

Since I don't do PHP development I wasn't originally aware of the PHP plugin for Netbeans. You can find it listed in the plugins (Tools > Plugins) for Netbeans and should provide a much better environment for PHP work, with, I'm assuming, better PHP parsing and syntax highligting.

Comment: this does not help, although it seems it should :(

Comment: Oh look, there's a PHP plugin for Netbeans. I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I would just click on the hint on the **left** side by the line numbers, it should create a pop-up, while that's still **up** click on the hint again. Now another pop-up will be there asking if you want to turn off the error check for either that single file, or for all files. Choose for **that** file, b/c it should be off by default.

Answer (score 1):

I have no 6.9 at hands, but in 7.x (and believe so, for some time)
go to Options->Editor->Hints-> and uncheck

```
[ ] CSS (all those rules together)
[ ] HTML Validator (ditto)
```

Did the trick for me, when working with proprietary template files, 'coincidentally' named .html ...

Comment: Its actually in  Options->Editor->Hints->language->HTML and uncheck