# Disabling/delaying red underlining in NetBeans 6.9.1

Tags: java, netbeans

I've done a decent amount of searching and can't find an answer anywhere. Anyway, that it underlines statements in red as I type them is pretty annoying. Now, the red underlining can be very helpful, so is there a way to delay it? Or, failing that, removing it completely?

Comment: It is normally delayed while you are typing. It only appears when you stop typing. Are you typing very slow?

Comment: I can't find a way to change the delay settings but its possible to turn this off. check the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693034/netbeans-disable-error-checking-underline

check the screenshot and change the value set for error from "Wave Underlined" to "None". Please note that after you click OK, you will not see changes until you make a new change in the editor (like typing a letter or anything) after which the new settings will take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Options > Fonts and Colours > Category: Error

... just remove/adapt the format to your needs.